# Why Dividend Yield differs for the same company on different birga?

Tags: dividends, investment-strategies, european-union, stock-dividend

Why European tickers of American dividends stocks has not dividend yield?

Does it mean that for dividend strategy I should buy on US birgas, not on local European ones? Will it affect my taxes?

For example:

> DY is 3.16% on https://www.google.com/finance/quote/TSN:NYSE
>
> DY is '-' on https://www.google.com/finance/quote/TF7A:ETR

the same for:

- Intel:

> 5.18% https://www.google.com/finance/quote/INTC:NASDAQ
>
> '-' https://www.google.com/finance/quote/INL:ETR

- Verison:

> 6.55% https://www.google.com/finance/quote/VZ:NYSE
>
> '-' https://www.google.com/finance/quote/BAC:ETR

Comment: I think Google finance just doesn't display it. There is also no PE ratio. There is a price, and there are earnings...

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug.... because I found the same instrument on bank page and there is DIVe 5.07%  https://www.comdirect.de/inf/aktien/detail/uebersicht.html?SEARCH_REDIRECT=true&REDIRECT_TYPE=WKN&REFERER=search.general&ID_NOTATION=9620544&SEARCH_VALUE=868402